# What's the highest critical hit damage a level 1 character can do?

Tags: optimization, pathfinder-2e, critical-hit

What's the highest critical hit damage a level 1 character can do?

Rules:

- The character must be level 1
- The character cannot have any magical items
- The character's starting equipment must be affordable with the standard 15 gp start
- The character can be assisted by up to three other level 1 characters with the same restrictions
- The three assistant characters each have one round before the primary character makes their attack
- The damage must come off of one critical hit (i.e. the first hit of Flurry of Blows, not both)
- Max damage can be assumed
- Don't count persistent damage - theoretically any amount of persistent damage could be infinite if the enemy never manages to stop it somehow. Additionally, it's not part of the immediate damage of the critical.
- Characters can be assumed to know that this is going to happen; therefore, they can start with weapons and items drawn so long as they can properly hold them in their hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

120, the party is as follows, a bard, 2 alchemists, and dwarven fighter

**Builds for each class**

Bard:

- [Magic weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=182) spell
- [Inspire courage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=386) Focus spell

Alchemists:

- [Giant Centipede venom](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=113)
- [Energy mutagen](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=474) (fire)[Uncommon]

Fighter

- Strength 18
- Dwarf ancestry feat [vengeful hatred](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=6)
- Class feat [power attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=359),
- [Greatpick](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=23) w/ affixed [Owlbear Claw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=230) token

**Actions for each**

Bard:

1. Cast magic weapon on the fighter's greatpick
2. Previous action requires 2 actions
3. Use inspire courage

Alchemist 1:

1. Draw giant centipede venom from bandoleer and apply it to the fighter's greatpick
2. Previous action requires 2 actions
3. draw an energy mutagen(fire) from bandoleer and pour it down the fighter's throat.

Alchemist 2:

1. Draw giant centipede venom from bandoleer and apply it to their own weapon
2. Previous action requires 2 actions
3. strike to apply stage 1 giant centipede venom to target

Fighter

1. Power attack on a valid vengeful hatred target
2. Previous action requires 2 actions
3. ??

**Damage breakdown:**

Greatpick does a d10 but has the fatal(d12) trait that changes the weapon dice to d12s on a crit and adds an extra d12 ~ 3d12

Power attack adds an extra damage dice (2 on a crit) ~5d12

Magic weapon adds an extra damage dice (2 on a crit) ~7d12

Giant centipede poison has a stage 1 poison damage of 1d6, a stage 2 venom damage of 1d8, and a stage 3 damage of (1d12) so assuming that the target critically fails the fort save and that they also failed the previous poisioning they advance from stage 1 to stage 3 ~ 7d12+1d12

18 strength add 4 damage or 8 on a crit ~8d12+8

Inspire courage adds +1 status bonus to damage or 2 on a a crit ~ 8d12+10

Energy Mutagen adds 1 point of fire damage or 2 on a crit ~8d12+12

Vengeful Hatred add damage equal to the weapon damage dice which is 6 ~8d12+18

Owlbear token grants critical specialization effects 1 hit hit when consumed which for a pick adds damage equal to the number of weapon dice which is 6 ~8d12+24

**total**

8x12+24 = 120 and stage 3 giant centipede venom

*feel free to edit for clarity*

Comment: You forgot to note the d12 from poison on the poison line item (it says 7 but is 8 at that point) You included it on the next line. However, it should be 4 (*maybe* 5) weapon dice, not 6. (Normal, striking magic, Fatal, PA, *maybe* crit). This will reduce Owlbear token and Vengeful Hatred to 4(8) each (*or 5(10)*). I would rule that, even if the GM allowed rolling the crit dice they do not count toward weapon dice, personally.

Comment: @CaptianObvious I think it most consistent with allowing weapons to be "pre-drawn" to allow items to be "pre-drawn" as well. Obviously characters can only hold so much in their hands. This means that you can probably make your alchemist actions work.